# Could not copy the assembly '/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll'

Tags: mono, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Every time I'm trying to deploy my project I'm getting the following error:

> Compiling to native code /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -sdkroot
>   "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" --cache
>   "/Users/user/Desktop/Source/iOS/obj/iPhone/Release/mtouch-cache"
>   --nomanifest --nosign -dev "/Users/user/Desktop/Source/iOS/bin/iPhone/Release/iOS.app"
>   -r

...

> -linksdkonly -sdk "7.1" -targetver "7.1" --abi=armv7 "/Users/user/Desktop/iOS/bin/iPhone/Release/iOS.exe"
>   Xamarin.iOS 7.2.6 Business Edition using framework:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk
>   error MT1009: Could not copy the assembly
>   '/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll' to
>   '/Users/user/Desktop/iOS/obj/iPhone/Release/mtouch-cache/Link/monotouch.dll':
>   Access to the path
>   "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll.mdb" or
>   "/Users/user/Desktop/iOS/obj/iPhone/Release/mtouch-cache/Link/monotouch.dll.mdb"
>   is denied.

I cleaned obj folder - no luck.
I reastarted the mac - no luck.
I tried to go to /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll but wasn't able to access this folder - it says I have no right.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Update:**
Xamarin verified that issue exists and provided [KB article on about it with fix](http://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1649499-error-mt1009-could-not-copy-the-assembly).
All you have to do to fix that is run this in terminal:

```
sudo chmod 0644 /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll.mdb
```

---

Faced this problem on July 16, 2014.
Found [thread on Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15622) about this issue. Unfortunately, the latest alpha build of XS I had still had this problem and, unfortunately, solution was different to what is described in the thread.

I had to run `sudo chmod 777 /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/*` to fix access rights. Fixing rights in your project's bin/debug/whatever folder doesn't help.

P.S. I know 777 is not the best choice in terms of permissions, but it's just a single Mono folder, so it's acceptable for me.
P.P.S. So 0644 is the correct permission set ;)

Comment: P.S. don't forget to upvote the question itself. Without it, there would be no answer

Answer (score 2):

This did it for me:

```
sudo chmod 0644 /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll.mdb
```

*Source: http://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1649499-error-mt1009-could-not-copy-the-assembly*

### My current setup:

Xamarin Studio
Version 5.2 (build 386)

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 5.1.1 (5085)

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 7.2.6.28

Operating System
Mac OS X 10.9.4